# Задать семантично заголовок для списка nav или ul

Tags: html

Подменю. Есть вложенный список с заголовком.

```
<nav><ul><li>
    <a href="#">эл-2</a>
    <nav class="">
        <ul> ++ЗАГОЛОВОК++
            <li></li>                   
        </ul>
    </nav>
</li></ul></nav>
```

как будет семантично-правильно задать заголовок подменю? просто в ul первым элементом (пред li) сделать h3, например (`<ul><h3>++ЗАГОЛОВОК++</h3><li>`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вкладывать элемент навигации `nav` в другой элемент навигации `nav` - уже не семантично. Также, в элементе `ul` каждый элемент списка должен начинаться с тега `<li>` - иначе это тоже не семантично.

Вам нужно в первом элементе списка (не перед тегом `li`, а внутри него) указать заголовок, а если вам необходимо еще визуально выделить этот элемент, то просто добавьте элементу с заголовком класс и стилизуйте его. А после элемента с заголовком должен идти основной список. Примерно так:

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#">эл-2</a>
       <ul>
         <li class="caption"><h3>++ЗАГОЛОВОК++</h3></li>
         <li>...</li>    
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Другой вариант, если вам не нужно визуально показывать заголовок у подменю, вы можете вынести заголовок из списка и стилями визуально скрыть его, но при этом, необходимо чтобы заголовок оставался на странице.

HTML:

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <h3 class="hidden">++ЗАГОЛОВОК++</h3>
       <a href="#">эл-2</a>
       <ul>
         <li>...</li>    
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: СпасиБо! надеялся, что у ul или nav как-то можно задать атрибут, типа <ul title="Заголовок">. жаль, нет такого.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, на досуг почитать - хороший ресурс по сематике:
https://html5book.ru/html5-semantic-elements/

**P.S. Пишу тут, пока закрыты коментарии.**